# How to calculate byte size for deflater compression output in Android

Tags: android, compression

This is my code for compressing data using deflater in Android

```
    String inputString = "kjhdf948w37fh4ifh34789fh34789fh3489fh7348fh84f8h4f3";
    byte[] input = inputString.getBytes("UTF-8");

    // Compress the bytes
    byte[] output = new byte[100];
    Deflater compresser = new Deflater(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);
    compresser.setInput(input);
    compresser.finish();
    int compressedDataLength = compresser.deflate(output);
```

Now I want to fix the size of "output" byte array how can I set the size of the output byte array. Please, help me to come out from this issue.

```
  byte[] output = new byte[100];
```

Currently I set 100 how can I calculate the output byte array size dynamically based on input bytes.

Comment: simply, you can't ... do some data structure like `class TheData { public lenghtOfThisStructureInBytes; /*4 + 4 + compressed array lenght*/ public int lenghtOfTheDataBeforeCompression; byte[] theDataAfterCompression; }` (my assumption is that you wana send this byte array somewhere - so instead sending plain byte array send this structure ... now fx: if you are using sockets you can read 4 bytes cast them to int (len) then read (len - 4) bytes and you will get the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is from the [dev guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/Deflater.html)

```
 byte[] originalBytes = ...

 Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
 deflater.setInput(originalBytes);
 deflater.finish();

 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
 while (!deflater.finished()) {
     int byteCount = deflater.deflate(buf);
     baos.write(buf, 0, byteCount);
 }
 deflater.end();

 byte[] compressedBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

i think the trick is to set the buf size rationally small,
so you will gather your compressed bytes in the ByteArrayOutputStream, then you get array of compressed bytes once the while loop ends with the correct data length

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code from Deflator documentation which does exactly what you probably need:

```
 Deflater deflater = new Deflater(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);
 deflater.setInput(originalBytes);
 deflater.finish();

 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
 while (!deflater.finished()) {
     int byteCount = deflater.deflate(buf);
     baos.write(buf, 0, byteCount);
 }
 deflater.end();

 byte[] compressedBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

Since the size of output is unknown in advance, the buffer is allocated for 8K bytes (in your case it may be less) and there is a loop that reads the bytes and sends them to ByteArrayOutputStream untill all the bytes have been read.

Finally you get all the compressed output with

```
 byte[] compressedBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

A simpler way may be using DeflaterOutputStream

```
try {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Deflater deflater = new Deflater(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);
    deflater.setInput(originalBytes);
    DeflaterOutputStream dfos = new DeflaterOutputStream(baos, deflater);
    dfos.deflate();
    dfos.close();
    byte[] compressedBytes = baos.toByteArray();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStrackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: "`deflate()` has protected access". Should I use `flush()` instead?